# Insert one list into another list in position

Tags: java

For instance, there are two lists

```
List<String> goods = new ArrayList<String>();
goods.add("Vegetables");
goods.add("Foods");
goods.add("Drinks");

List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
foods.add("Beef");
foods.add("Chicken");
```

What is the best way to insert foods into goods into position of `Foods` i.e. into 1 position replacing the `Food` with the content of `foods`?

So that `goods` will contain:

> Vegetables, Beef, Chicken, Drinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List.addAll()`, but you *also* have to remove the `Foods` entry after doing the insertion.

```
goods.remove("Foods");  // remove by object (String name)
goods.addAll(1, foods);
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)) for `List.addAll(int index, Collection c)`:

> Inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this list, starting at the specified position. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (increases their indices).

Comment: This could be further improved. The number 1 is a magic String. It seems the intention is to be whatever position "Foods" was in. So it will be better to have 3 steps: find index of "Foods", remove by index, add all at index

Comment: @janos You are right, that answer can be improved, but i think the other way around because the question itself is about position. So the element _Foods_ is the magic in specific example. I suggest to remove by given index directly.

Comment: @irieill that's a possibility too. I assumed this way because we're replacing an item called "Foods" with a list named "foods". Only OP knows the truth ;)

Answer (score 0):

`goods.addAll(1, foods);`

`goods.remove("Foods");`will work.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)

Comment: This will not remove the entry _Foods_ in list _goods_ as wanted.

Comment: @irieill removed it from the list. I am on mobile. Please edit it if you think you could improve this answer. :)